# How to download a file (image,gif,etc..) in react native

Tags: react-native

> I have tried this code but my app is crashing without showing any error , i couldnt figure out what is the error

```
const {config,fs} = RNFetchBlob;
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir // this is the pictures directory. You can check the available directories in the wiki.
let options = {
fileCache: true,
addAndroidDownloads : {
    useDownloadManager : false, // setting it to true will use the device's native download manager and will be shown in the notification bar.
    notification : false,
    path:  PictureDir + "/me_image", // this is the path where your downloaded file will live in
    }
}
config(options).fetch('GET',url).then((res) => {
    alert('Done');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  saveToCameraRoll = () => {
    const{selectedImage, downlaodUrl} = this.state
    let url = downlaodUrl[0].url;
    ToastAndroid.show("Image is Saving...", ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    if (Platform.OS === 'android'){ 

      RNFetchBlob
        .config({
          fileCache : true,
          appendExt : 'jpg'
        })
        .fetch('GET', url)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log()
         CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(res.path())

            .then((res) => {
             console.log("save", res)
             ToastAndroid.show("Image saved Successfully.", ToastAndroid.SHORT)
            }).catch((error) => {
                ToastAndroid.show("Ops! Operation Failed", ToastAndroid.SHORT)

            })

        })
    } else {
        CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(url)
          .then(alert('Success', 'Photo added to camera roll!'))
          ToastAndroid.show("Image saved Successfully.", ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it is working like  a charm , And one more doubt how to store the downloaded file in specific folder

Comment: @TJagadishGupta you can do like this

Comment: RNFetchBlob.config({
            fileCache: true,
            appendExt: 'png',
          })
            .fetch('GET', currentImageUrl)
            .then(res => {
              CameraRoll.save(res.data, {type: 'photo', album: 'Name your folder'})
                .then(() => showImageSaveSuccessToast())
                .catch(() => showImageSaveFailureToast());
            })